# Magento Responsive Menu not positioned correctly

Tags: admin

Magento does not work as well on a phone as on a computer. When I use a Magento-based website on my phone, the top menu is below the image banner.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an issue with the third-party theme which you have installed. Please try to fix third party theme issue or else enable the default Magento luma theme. Magento 2 provides a default theme with responsive and desktop supported.